# Azure Service Bus Publish to Specific Consumer

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a case where I need to publish messages directly to individual consumers instead of to a queue. For example, we want to send notifications to users of our app specific to them. To do this I figure I would need to store some type of client token on the server side and then publish to that token, perhaps a routing key.

This seems like a pretty common scenario yet I couldn't find any info on it.

[image]

***Update***
I tested out subscriptions and topics but there is a limit of the number of subscriptions per topic so this solution won't work.

I'd be very surprised if the service bus doesn't have some sort of provision to handle this.
Could there be a different Azure messaging service to accomplish this same task?

Comment: Have you looked at Service Bus Topics & Subscriptions? They are meant for that purpose only.

Comment: I did. Everything I read said they were intended for a one to many publishing. I'll take another look though, maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and describe your scenario in more details please? May be I misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: I added a diagram showing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Topics and Subscriptions would fit the bill perfectly. Basically you would create a subscription for each user and then define filtering rule on the subscriptions so that messages are routed properly.

Comment: I didn't know about filtering rules, I'll check it out

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions. HTH.

Comment: I tested out subscriptions and found that it has a limitation on the number of subscriptions per topic so this won't work.